# Consume Salesforce REST Service through MuleSoft

Tags: rest, salesforce, mule

I wanna consume a REST service exposed by Salesforce, right now I'm using a Sandbox instance and using Anypoint Studio to create my flow, I would like to know what's the best practice to implement it. Now I'm not sure about the salesforce connector allows me to consume the service, so, I'm using this components:

This is whole flow.

```
<mule xmlns:sfdc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sfdc" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm" xmlns:oauth2="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth2" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.6.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sfdc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sfdc/current/mule-sfdc.xsd">
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="https://test.salesforce.com" port="80"  doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" protocol="HTTPS">
        <oauth2:client-credentials-grant-type clientId="3xQYwWqsvZUYbwMRLHiXQy9A23XXXtxg1OMxdXh5p4eoev53q26CmN0Yx0EyLf_HTLW9X" clientSecret="710XXX1723685311">
            <oauth2:token-request tokenUrl="https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token"/>
        </oauth2:client-credentials-grant-type>
    </http:request-config>
    <file:connector name="File" writeToDirectory="/Users/emoran/Desktop" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
    <flow name="outbrain_3wintegrationFlow1">
        <poll doc:name="Poll">
            <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="10" timeUnit="SECONDS"/>
            <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="services/apexrest/outbrain_integration_messages/" method="GET" requestStreamingMode="ALWAYS" sendBodyMode="ALWAYS"  doc:name="Consume SFDC LOG Service" doc:description="prueba" parseResponse="false" source="#[message.payload]" target="#[message.payload]">
                <http:request-builder>
                </http:request-builder>
                <http:success-status-code-validator values="0..599"/>
            </http:request>
        </poll>
        <logger message="&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt; RESPONSE FROM SERVER:  #[message.payload]" level="DEBUG" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="/" outputPattern="refacciones.json" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

What would be the best approach to consume this service?

Edgar,

Comment: If it is a REST endpoint, why would it be different if it is exposed via Salesforce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce connector in Mule allows you to consume all the services exposed by Salesforce. You should use Salesforce connector within you poll scope to get data from Salesforce.

A simple example for your requirement is shown below.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:sfdc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sfdc" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
 xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.2"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sfdc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sfdc/current/mule-sfdc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd">
    <context:property-placeholder location="file:${mule_home}/conf/salesforce-config.properties"/>
    <sfdc:config name="Salesforce" doc:name="Salesforce" password="${sf_password}" securityToken="${sf_security_token}" url="${sf_url}" username="${sf_username}">
        <sfdc:connection-pooling-profile initialisationPolicy="INITIALISE_ONE" exhaustedAction="WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW"/>
    </sfdc:config>
    <flow name="sfdcpollerFlow1" doc:name="sfdcpollerFlow1">
        <poll doc:name="Poll">
            <sfdc:get-updated config-ref="Salesforce"  doc:name="Salesforce" duration="10" type="Contract"/>
        </poll>
        <logger message="RESPONSE FROM SERVER:  #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="${file_path}" outputPattern="refacciones.json" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

In the above example, I am fetching modified contacts and placing that to a folder. You can refer the mule soft documents for more details on Salesforce connector.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Salesforce+Connector
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Connect+with+Salesforce+Example

Comment: Thanks, in the end to use salesforce connector is better than expose a service, get all information and transforme it. It is the best approach and best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Using the HTTP connector in Mule to interface with Salsforce's Rest API is perfectly valid. However as others have mentioned the Salesforce connector abstracts away a lot for complexity when dealing with the Salesforce APIs including authentication and connection management etc.

I noticed your example uses OAuth, the other examples are using basic/ws security but the  Salesforce connector also support OAuth: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Salesforce+Connector+Authentication

However under the hood the Salesforce connector primarily uses the Salesforce SOAP API. So if you have a particular need to use the Rest API then the connector might not help.